# How can I rebuild the cache for a specific route when a node of type foo is updated?

Tags: routes, caching, 10

I created a page by a module and the cache of that page must be deleted if a node of node-type 'foo' is updated.

How do I do that?

I read https://www.drupal.org/docs/drupal-apis/cache-api/cache-tags

And tried:

mymodule.routing.yml

```
mymodule.foopage:
  path: '/myurl'
  defaults:
    _controller: '\Drupal\mymodule\MyClass::page'
    _title: 'Foo'
  options:
    _cache_tags:
      - 'node:foo'
  requirements:
    _permission: 'access content'
```

I tried also `_cache_tags` `node_list:foo`

But cache is not rebuild when I update a foo content.

`drupal_flush_all_caches` works fine, but it seems a bit to heavy.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The cache tag `node_list:foo` is correct. But I've never seen that you can add it to a route like this. Normally the route controller returns the cache metadata in $build:

```
public function page() {
  // build $build
  $build['#cache']['tags'][] = 'node_list:foo';
  return $build;
}
```